# Trying to change an element value inside an Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some value from the local storage. The value is made out of an array which includes objects which includes elements inside theme,
I'm trying to change specific elemnt's value inside one of the objects and set it back to local storage.

```
let x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Checker"));
var y = JSON.parse(x);
var z = JSON.parse(y[1])
```

This is the value of var `z` :

```
{task: " t", date: "2020-03-02", time: "01:01", number: 1}
```

My question is how do I change element "numbers" which is correctly setted to 1, to 4 and set it back to local storage?

Comment: This is basic of JavaScript `z.number = 4`

Comment: Why would you use a structure that requires to `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(...)))`?

Answer (score 0):

change x to the value that you want and then use:

```
localStorage.setItem('Checker', JSON.stringify(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the json object back in local storage using `JSON.stringyfy()` method.

```
let x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Checker"));
var y = JSON.parse(x);
var z = JSON.parse(y[1])
```

**EDITED**

```
    z.number = 4;
    y[1] = z
    console.log(y);
    localStorage.setItem("Checker " , JSON.stringify(y));
```

Comment: This is not useful, because its changes the whole value of "Checker" to the Z and delete every other object...

Comment: Okk so you want to update only certain value . @SahiBalata

Comment: Checkout my updated code . It will solve your problem . @SahiBalata

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` is recursive, when it's applied on `x`, it will be applied on any object nested within it:

```
var x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Checker"));
x[1].number = 4;
localStorage.setItem("Checker", JSON.stringify(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrace your steps backwards. Something like

```
// z == {task: " t", date: "2020-03-02", time: "01:01", number: 1}

z.number = 4;
y[1] = JSON.stringify(z);
localStorage.setItem("Checker", JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(y)));
```

I think.

But storing data this way is just asking for bugs.